Flutter: 'build_runner' not generating the '.g.dart' file
running 'dart run build_runner watch' isn't generating 'g.dart' file
Here is the code - annotation provided, 'part' added - name of the file is correct.

Dependencies are added correctly.
When i run build_runner, it gives no error, but it doesn't return the prompt

Tried running dart run build_runner clean. It didn't help.

Tried with relative path -


part 'lib/providers/products_provider.g.dart';
This didn't help.

Checked if flutter sdk path to environment variable 'Path'

Want to know what I'm missing here. Thanks.

**

UPDATE

**
Hello everyone, it's working now. Ran

'flutter clean',
'flutter pub get',
'dart run build_runner watch'

'g.dart' file is generated now.
It works now, and I will attempt the same if I face this issue again. But want to understand why we need to clean and pub get again.
Thanks for your help!

can you share your dependencies in pubspec yaml (to check versions of build_runner, riverpod and riverpod generator in dependencies and dev_dependencies) and if you hava a build.yaml maybe its ignoring that route

Welcome to stackoverflow. To make it easier for readers, source code should be added as text. That makes it possible to copy/paste in case someone wants to write an answer or maybe run your code.

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
flutter_riverpod: ^2.5.1
riverpod_annotation: ^2.3.5
dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter
flutter_lints: ^4.0.0
build_runner: ^2.4.12
riverpod_generator: ^2.4.3
hive_generator: ^2.0.1

So the code you've provided looks correct. Please check dependencies correctly
dev_dependencies:
a tool for running code generators
build_runner:
the code generator
riverpod_generator:
riverpod_lint makes it easier to work with Riverpod
riverpod_lint:
import custom_lint too as riverpod_lint depends on it
custom_lint:
and
flutter pub get

On a side note, please add the type annotation for the ref parameter. So it should be List<Product> products(ProductsRef ref) {.

Hello everyone, it's working now.
Ran

'flutter clean',
'flutter pub get',
'dart run build_runner watch'

'g.dart' file is generated now.
It works now, and I will attempt the same if I face this issue again. But want to understand why we need to clean and pub get again. Thanks for your help!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

it is not needed to make clean before. the usual reasons are: 1- the code does not compile, 2 - the .g.dart file name is not equals to the current file name 3 - you missed @riverpod definition 4- (sneaky!) the .g.dart file is opened by vscode.
